# Why is the fat arrow in a class method not binding to the parent scope's this?

Tags: javascript, class, lambda, ecmascript-6

I've got an ES2015 code snippet where I'm trying to dynamically populate the objects `this.data.pageCategoryL1~3` keys with different data depending on the state of the `originalData`. I'm passing class methods as a callback to `_categoryMapper`, which isn't binding the callback to class's `this` - it's only passing a pointer to the function without binding it even though it's a method. That alone seems weird odd that it isn't automatically bound to the instance.

The truly puzzling part though: inside of `_categoryMapper`'s reduce function, the fat arrow function's `this` is `undefined`. I thought fat arrows were supposed to bind to their parent `this`'s scope?

```js
class AnalyticsData {
  constructor(originalData) {

    this.data = {};
    this.originalData = originalData;
  }

  mapCategories() {
    debugger;
    let mappedCategories = {
      pageCategoryL1: '',
      pageCategoryL2: '',
      pageCategoryL3: ''
    };
    if (this.originalData.search && this.originalData.search.refinements) {
      mappedCategories = this._categoryMapper({
          pageCategoryL1: 'categoryl1',
          pageCategoryL2: 'categoryl2',
          pageCategoryL3: 'categoryl3'
        },
        this._getSomeCategory); // if i bind only here it will work, because it doesn't use fat arrow's this
    } else if (this.originalData.items) {
      mappedCategories = this._categoryMapper({
          pageCategoryL1: 'a',
          pageCategoryL2: 'b',
          pageCategoryL3: 'c'
        },
        this._getSomeOtherCategory);
    }
    return mappedCategories;
  }

  _categoryMapper(mapping, callback) {

    return Object.keys(mapping).reduce((acc, key) => {
  // fat arrow in reduce should be implicitly bound to this
   console.log(this);
      let category = callback(mapping[key]).bind(this);
      acc[key] = category ? category : '';
      return acc;
    }, {});
  }

  _getSomeCategory(categoryKey) {
  // No access to this as currently written
  console.log(this) 
    let refinements = this.originalData.search.refinements;
    let matchedObj = refinements.find(({
      refinement
    }) => categoryKey === refinement.name);
    return matchedObj && matchedObj.refinement.value;
  }

  _getSomeOtherCategory(categoryKey) {
    let id = Object.keys(this.originalData.items)[0];
    return this.originalData.items[id][categoryKey];
  }
}

window.x = new AnalyticsData({
  search: {
    refinements: [{
      refinement: {
        name: 'categoryl1',
        value: 'yup'
      }
    }]
  }
}).mapCategories()
console.log(x)
  /* this.data should be: {
        pageCategoryL1: 'yup',
        pageCategoryL2: '',
        pageCategoryL3: ''
      };*/
```

Comment: Are you saying that `console.log(this);` in the reduce function reports undefined, or are you referring to how the `callback` function isn't bound to `this`?

Comment: `console.log(this)` was reporting undefined due to chrome debugger and babel not matching on what `this` was called. `call` does work, but while debugging I need to look at the transpiled version to log what `this` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misusing [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) here.

```
let category = callback(mapping[key]).bind(this);
```

`bind` creates a copy of a function with `this` set to whatever you passed it and zero or more arguments preloaded.

```js
function log(argument1) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(argument1);
}

let f = log.bind({ a: 1 }, 'a');
let g = log.bind({ b: 2 }, 'b');

f();
g();
```

What you probably want to use is [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which *calls* a function with `this` set to it's first argument.

```js
function log(argument1) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(argument1);
}

log.call({ a: 1 }, 'a');
log.call({ b: 2 }, 'b');
```

The reason `this === undefined` is that `callback` is not defined with an arrow function nor does it have any other way of defining what `this` should be. This is essentially what you're doing.

```js
'use strict';

let obj = {
  a: 1,
  log() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

function callCallback(callback) {
  callback();
}

// This is what you want to happen
callCallback(obj.log.bind(obj));

// This is what you're doing
callCallback(obj.log);
```

Comment: Understood. But that still doesn't answer the question of why the fat arrow `this` scope is `undefined`.

Comment: @user3704512 Yes it does. `callback` is not defined with an arrow function. You're calling `callback` all by itself so it doesn't have a `this` value. I'll update my answer to explain.

Comment: Thank you! My confusion was stemming from babel transpiling and using the chrome debugger.
I was doing console.log(this) instead of console.log(_this5)
the categoryMapper method transpiled looks like this: 

`var _this5 = this;`
            `return Object.keys(mapping).reduce(function (acc, key) {`
              `console.log("I should not be undefined:" + _this5);`
              `var category = callback.call(_this5, mapping[key]);`
              `acc[key] = category ? category : '';`
              `return acc;`
            `}, {});`